# How do you add a folder that starts with a dot (.name) to SVN's global-ignores list?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do you a dd a folder that starts with a dot (.name) to SVN's global-ignores list?

I want that folder, all its subfolders and files to be excluded, yet adding `.name` only seems to exclude the folder itself.

I'm using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: svn ignores hidden files by default - file names starting with a dot.

Comment: The "leading dot hides the file" convention does not apply on Windows, which is the only place TortoiseSVN runs.

Comment: Did anyone ever find the answer to this?  2019, and I'm still having to manually ignore every single hidden folder when I want to ignore them all, all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Per [TortoiseSVN docs](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html):

> add the file to the `svn:global-ignores` list using `TortoiseSVN → Add to
>   ignore list (recursively)` This will affect the directory on which you
>   set the `svn:global-ignores` property and all subfolders as well.

Comment: That's what I tried. I added `.name`to the `svn:global-ignores` list, yet `.name/foo.txt` still showed up in the Commit dialogue...

Answer (score -1):

In Tortoise SVN with GUI, you can right click on a svn folder, clock tortoise settings, and then in general you can enter in the global ignore pattern.

Use regular expression square brackets to start a folder with a "." (dot)

```
[.]vs
```